# Why are the results from terminal and bash script different?

Tags: linux, bash

```
USER@HOST:~:$ cat .bashrc
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific aliases and functions
alias sudo='sudo -i'
```

```
USER@HOST:~:$ cat tmp.sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo env | grep PATH
```

```
USER@HOST:~:$ ./tmp.sh
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

```
USER@HOST:~:$ sudo env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/python-3.8.2-r2/bin:/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

I put an alias setting in my `.bashrc` file.

When I test it through a terminal, it's okay.

But it seems to work differently when done with a script.

What's the difference here, and how can I test this through script?

Answer (score 1):

The alias does not apply to the script. You'll see the equivalent if you use `command` to bypass alias expansion in the shell:

```
$ command sudo env | grep PATH
```

Comment: Yes, it is. Then how can I figure out in a shell script whether the alias is set properly?

Comment: You have to enable alias expansion expiliitly. But your script should be independent of the interactive environment from which it is executed. If your script needs the `-i` option to be included, write `sudo -i` rather than relying on the caller to have such an alias defined.